# How to disable Scheduled queries in Big Query Console

Tags: google-bigquery

I have close to 1000 queries scheduled in the big query cloud platform. However i would now have to pause all of them. One approach is to manually disable one after the other, but this would be an exhaustive task. Is there any way to disable all the active queries in one go?

Answer (score 2):

Disabling scheduled queries (transfer) is not supported by the CLI, but it can be done using Console/API:

**Document Link:**
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/working-with-transfers

> **Disabling a transfer using API document:**
> https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/reference/datatransfer/rest/v1/projects.locations.transferConfigs/patch

**List transfer config names:**

```
bq ls --transfer_config --transfer_location=US --format=prettyjson | jq '.[].name'
```